# Would someone check my work finding the joint distribution for two RVs X and Y?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, transformation, multivariate-statistical-analysis

### **Question**

**U**, **V**, follow independent univariate normal with mean zero and variance one. Let **X** = **U** and **Y** = p**U**+$\sqrt{1-p^2}$**V** where $|p|$ < 1.

$\Sigma_{XY} = \pmatrix{1 & p \\ p & 1}$

Find the joint distribution of **X**,**Y**.

### **My Work**

I note that **U** and **V** are independent univariate normal. Define **Z** = $\pmatrix{U \\ V}$ and **W** = $\pmatrix{X \\ Y}$. Let **W** = **B** * **Z** where **B** is a 2x2 constant matrix, then **W** ~ **MVN**(**B**$\mu$, **B**$\Sigma_{UV}$$\textbf{B}^T$).

\begin{align}
\pmatrix{X \\ Y} = \textbf{B}\pmatrix{U \\V} \\ \pmatrix{\textbf{U} \\ p\textbf{U} + \sqrt{1-p^2}\textbf{V}} = \textbf{B}\pmatrix{U \\V} \\ B = \pmatrix{b_{11} & b_{12} \\ b_{21} & b_{22}} \\ \therefore \pmatrix{b_{11}U + b_{12}V \\b_{21}U + b_{22}V} = \pmatrix{\textbf{U} \\ p\textbf{U} + \sqrt{1-p^2}\textbf{V}} \\ \Rightarrow \matrix{b_{11}=1& b_{12}=0\\b_{21} =p & b_{22} = \sqrt{1-p^2}} \\ \textbf{B} = \pmatrix{1&0\\p&\sqrt{1-p^2}}\\ \therefore\textbf{W} =\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\p & \sqrt{1-p^2}}*\pmatrix{U \\V}
\end{align}

So we have

**B**$\mu$ = $\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\p & \sqrt{1-p^2}} * \pmatrix{0 \\ 0} = \pmatrix{0 \\0}$ and

**B**$\Sigma_{UV}\textbf{B}^T$ = $\Sigma_{XY}$ and therefore **W** ~ **MVN**$\pmatrix{\pmatrix{0 \\0}, & \pmatrix{1 & p \\ p & 1}}$

Which can be written explicitly as

$$ 
f_{XY} = \frac{1}{2\pi * \sqrt{det(\Sigma_{XY})}}*e^{\frac{-1}{2}(\textbf{W} - \mu)^T\Sigma_{XY}^{-1}(\textbf{W} - \mu)} 
$$

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do, nor what the question is. In any case, $X,Y$ is a gaussian with mean zero and covariance $\Sigma$

Comment: Trying to do a transformation to get the joint distribution of X,Y by multiplying Z by B

Comment: Although, I think I may have misinterpreted what to do here, and after thinking about your comment, I think I see where the mistake was.